# Joining 2 select queries from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I have **two SQL queries** from same table as follows.

```
Query1 -> select * from (select (start_date::text), (end_date::text), count("NEW") "NEW" from table_name where refnum in (select refnum from table_name where start_date in (SELECT start_date FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)) and "NEW">0 group by start_date, end_date order by end_date DESC limit 10) top_10 order by end_date ASC

Query2 -> select * from (select (start_date::text), (end_date::text), count("DELETED") "DELETED" from table_name where refnum in (select refnum from table_name where start_date in (SELECT start_date FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)) and "DELETED">0 group by start_date, end_date order by end_date DESC limit 10) top_10 order by end_date ASC
```

Please suggest a final query to merge these two sub queries resulting in one single table

I want the final table containing columns **start_date, end_date, NEW, DELETED**

Comment: What columns do you want to use to join? `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: yes,  start_date and end_date

Comment: There are *much* better solutions. Can you provide your Postgres version and the table definition (`CREATE TABLE table_name ..` statement), showing data types and constraints.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter version 9.x

Comment: Before Postgres 10, the major Postgres version included the second digit. See: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ So 9.6? Also please provide a description of what the queries are supposed to achieve. There are several pieces of SQL in there that *look* like possible misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FULL JOIN` as in:

```
select 
  coalesce(a.start_date, b.start_date) as start_date,
  coalesce(a.end_date, b.end_date) as end_date,
  a.new,
  b.deleted
from (
  -- query #1 here; exclude the ORDER BY clause
) a
full join (
  -- query #2 here; exclude the ORDER BY clause
) b on b.start_date = a.start_date and b.end_date = a.end_date
order by coalesce(a.end_date, b.end_date) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You ***can*** use a `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` like was suggested. **But** be aware that rows do not match on `NULL` values! If one of your result rows has `NULL` in `start_date` or `end_date`, "matching" rows are not combined. There are workarounds, but I am not going into this as I don't expect it to apply. Also, your queries would already break at `order by end_date DESC` which sorts `NULL` values first - probably unintended ...

Either way, **if** you go for the `FULL JOIN`, do it with a `USING` clause:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date, a.new, b.deleted
FROM        ( <"top_10" subquery of Query1 here> ) a
FULL   JOIN ( <"top_10" subquery of Query2 here> ) b USING (start_date, end_date)  -- !
ORDER  BY end_date;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> A clause of the form `USING ( a, b, ... )` is shorthand for `ON left_table.a = right_table.a AND left_table.b = right_table.b ....`
> Also, `USING` implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns
> will be included in the join output, not both.

The need for `COALESCE(a.start_date, b.start_date)` etc. goes away. Shorter, simpler, faster.

You ***might*** even go for a `NATURAL` join:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date, a.new, b.deleted
FROM              a
NATURAL FULL JOIN b  -- !
ORDER   BY end_date;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> `NATURAL` is shorthand for a `USING` list that mentions all columns in the
> two tables that have matching names. If there are no common column
> names, `NATURAL` is equivalent to `ON TRUE`.

Only makes sense if your subqueries strictly fit the description, and that won't change. I have only seen very few cases where that's advisable.

However, all of this is probably **putting lipstick on a pig**. Typically, you should be able to merge both queries into one - simplifying (and fixing) what you currently have.

Show us the exact table definition and an exact job description and chances are I can replace this sentence with a much better query for you.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `union` operator to stack the tables:

```
select * from (select (start_date::text), (end_date::text), count("NEW") "NEW" from table_name where refnum in (select refnum from table_name where start_date in (SELECT start_date FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)) and "NEW">0 group by start_date, end_date order by end_date DESC limit 10) top_10 order by end_date ASC
UNION
select * from (select (start_date::text), (end_date::text), count("DELETED") "DELETED" from table_name where refnum in (select refnum from table_name where start_date in (SELECT start_date FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)) and "DELETED">0 group by start_date, end_date order by end_date DESC limit 10) top_10 order by end_date ASC
```

Comment: This was my first try .... it throws "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"
"

Comment: Did you try removing the order by and putting it after the whole query?